# Simplifying a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been using below query to get the desired value and it gives me the correct output, but is there any way to simplify this query?

```
SELECT (
(SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM table1
WHERE date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-20'
AND page_urlpath like '%accountc/upgrade%'
AND page_urlpath like '%success%'
AND app_id = 'rapper') + 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM table1
WHERE date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-20'
AND page_urlpath like '%/upgrade/personal/success/%'
AND app_id = 'rapper') + 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM table1
WHERE date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-20'
AND page_urlpath like '%/upgrade/team/success/%'
AND app_id = 'rapper') + 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM table1
WHERE date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-20'
AND page_urlpath like '%/upgrade/desktop/personal/success/%'
AND app_id = 'rapper') + 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM table1
WHERE date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-20'
AND page_urlpath like '%/upgrade/desktop/team/success/%'
AND app_id = 'rapper') 
) as total
```

All the columns are in a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single pass query with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FILTER (
        WHERE page_urlpath LIKE '%accountc/upgrade%' AND
              page_urlpath like '%success%' OR
              page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/personal/success/%' OR
              page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/team/success/%' OR
              page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/desktop/personal/success/%' OR
              page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/desktop/team/success/%'
    ) AS total
FROM table1
WHERE
     app_id = 'rapper' AND
     date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-20';
```

In case you are on an older version of Postgres which doesn't support `FILTER`, use conditional aggregation with `CASE`:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN page_urlpath LIKE '%accountc/upgrade%' AND
                  page_urlpath like '%success%' OR
                  page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/personal/success/%' OR
                  page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/team/success/%' OR
                  page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/desktop/personal/success/%' OR
                  page_urlpath LIKE '%/upgrade/desktop/team/success/%'
             THEN 1 END) AS total
FROM table1
WHERE
     app_id = 'rapper' AND
     date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-20';
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, thank you for your reply, but I'm getting this error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4:     COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FILTER (
                                           ^

Comment: @David Maybe your version of Postgres doesn't support `FILTER`.  I have updated my answer with a version which should run on any version of Postgres (and really any SQL database).

Comment: Note this is not equivalent to the query in the original question, because it will only count each value of `user_id` 0–1 times, whereas the original question may count the same one up to 5 times because it sums five `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`. None of the `page_urlpath` constraints are mutually exclusive, so in the question's query, multiple subqueries may even match the same row, and of course they can match the same user ID across multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use regular expression to combine all page_urlpath ref: [similar to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) clause

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM   table1
WHERE  date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND    '2022-01-20'
AND    (
              page_urlpath similar TO '%(\/upgrade\/personal\/success\/|\/upgrade\/team\/success\/|\/upgrade\/desktop\/personal\/success/|\/upgrade\/desktop\/team\/success\/)%'
       OR     (
                     page_urlpath LIKE '%accountc\/upgrade%'
              AND    page_urlpath LIKE '%success%'))
AND    app_id='rapper';
```